# Apache Mod_ReWrite Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I had mod_rewrite set on my server to rewrite a url like the following

```
http://www.example.com/1
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?show=1
```

In order words a URL shortern. Everything was working fine when the system was running under a sub-domain on my development site, but now it just generates a `Not Found` error, although if I manually enter the url `/index.php?show=1` it works fine.

So the only changes is the urls switching from

`http://www.site.example.com`

to

`http://www.site.com`

however it's still running on the same server and the same sub-folder inside `public_html` on the server just the new domain name has been pointed to that folder.

The folder it's stored in is `/public_html/paste`

The full .htaccess file running in the directory is

```
# Set Default File
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Turn ReWrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Create Rule To Write URLs To Shorter Versions
RewriteRule /([a-z0-9]+) /index.php?show=$1
```

I can't enable RewriteLog as the hosting doesn't allow it for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure your host has mod_rewrite and allows htaccess overriding?

Comment: Definitely as I said it was working perfectly when accessed via a sub-domain but has only failed when I set it up with it's own domain. It's still running on the same server, account and with the same host. Plus I have another site running on that server too which is using mod_write perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the `AllowOverride` directive is not properly set for that folder. In your Apache configuration, you should make sure that the Directory or Vhost you're using for the primary domain has the `AllowOverride` set to `All`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Tried this solution and the one above but neither seems to have helped. According to my host mod_rewrite is working just fine and it must be a problem with the site config but I have scoured my config and there isn't any errors. Just about to try doing some simple other rewrites from the same directory so see if it's a mod_rewrite problem or a config issue with site

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify the RewriteBase directive.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

I'll also note that  `Options +FollowSymlinks` would be good to have in there too in case you ever turn it off further up the config chain (rewrite wont work without it).